# Service Worker support in chrome webview

Tags: service-worker, google-chrome-webview

Is Service Worker supported in chrome webview for android, if yes then from which version is it supported. Tried googling, but didn't find proper information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per [this announcement](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2015/03/android-webview-update.html), service workers have been supported in Chrome WebViews since March of 2015 (Android WebView v40+). Devices running Android OS 5.0 and higher should have it.

Since WebViews have their own sandboxed environment, the data cached by a service worker there won't be exposed to the normal Chrome application, and vice versa. If you were using [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), the cached data would be shared with the normal Chrome application.